# Fadein Body background Image

Tags: jquery, html, css

This may be considered a duplicate but I did trawl through similar questions and try the answers but cannot find a proper answer here or in WEB.
I have a background Image for the body set by  or by
   t.css('backgroundImage', 'url(' + url + ')');

However I am at a loss as to how to acheive fadeout/fadein effect because the usual techniques will fadein/out the body itself.I only need the image to fadein/out

Any help will be appreciated

thanks

Comment: Have you considered doing the effect directly on a PNG with transparency and then using that image?

Comment: I don't think you can. I think you'd have to assign the BG to an element positioned behind everything else and fade that in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do what you asked is what @vdbuilder said.

Take a look at this demo http://jsfiddle.net/AhmNP/

Comment: Thanks for taking the trouble.That approach works quite well.

Comment: @andrewk not me +1'd for picking up where I left off and providing working example!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a background image on the body you could use an image at the beginning of the body:

```
<img style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;left:0px;top:0px;z-index:-1;" src="/images/background.png" />
```

That way you can use the usual techniques to do  fadein/out on the image.